# Scope of Quantified Variables in the Axiom of Separation in ZF

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

I realize in the axiom of separation $$x\in A \leftrightarrow \phi(x)\wedge x\in B$$ the free variable $x$ is restricted to $B$ to avoid Russell's Paradox, but are the quantified variables in $\phi$ bounded by anything? In all of the formulations of the axiom I've seen, no specification has been made, except when a few of the variables are used to define a set with parameters. My question is, if there are variables in $\phi$ which can potentially be any element in the structure (which in the case of set theory is a set since all elements are themselves sets), what prevents them from assuming the value of $A$, the set which is being defined? While it may not be a direct case of a circular definition, I would think it could still lead to inconsistencies- almost of the same variety of Russell's Paradox.

Comment: There are indeed no additional restrictions. "While it may not be a direct case of a circular definition, I would think it could still lead to inconsistencies- almost of the same variety of Russell's Paradox." Why not try to derive an inconsistency in detail?

Comment: The meaning of the axiom is simply: from an **existing** set $B$, "carve out" a new set $A$ applying a condition $\phi(x)$ (a "specification"). Thus, the resulting set $A$ will be the subset of $B$ made of all and only those elements of $B$ that satisfy formula (condition) $\phi(x)$. As you can see, it is simply a restriction of [Comprehension principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension).

Comment: Thus, what is relevant in applying the axiom is that formula $\phi(x)$ specifying the condition has one free variable. If not, i.e. if we use a sentence (formula without free variables) what we get as $A$ is either all the original set $B$ (if the formula holds) ot the empty set (if formula does not hold).